# How to create schema for xml with root tag having sub-tags consisting values with restriction of different data types?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xsd.exe, xmlschema

How can the below XML be represented in XSD form when the sub-tags can be of different datatype values?

```
    <log>   
        <entries>
            <!-- below entry A1 can be true or false -->
            <entry name="A1" value="true"/>
            <!-- below entry A2 can take value 1 , 2 , 3 or 4 -->
            <entry name="A2" value="3" />
            <!-- below entry A3 can be V1, V2 or V3 -->
            <entry name="A3" value="V2" />
       </entries>
   </log>
```

The xsd.exe creates below but thats not exactly what i need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="log" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="log" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="entries">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="entry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: XSD 1.1 would do the job.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - Where can I get that? I think I already have the latest one which gives the output I don't need. Can you please share if you have the required output?

Comment: Not sure why the question is closed without giving proper details about where to locate xsd1.1 and how to use it. Firstly i can't locate xsd1.1 and secondly the linked question is not same as this question. I am adding a reqeust to re-open the question so that atleast some stubmling upon this question gets some credible answer and undetstanding.